# HTML tables with different styles

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two HTML tables on my page with two totally different styles. I don't want the style of first HTML table affecting the style of second HTML table, but somehow as soon as I define the style of second HTML table, the first HTML table gets affected too.

Below are the tables:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
</table>




  <table class="aTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

stylesheet:

```
.table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #FFF;
 
}

.table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #D8EBFB;
}

.table tr:first-child {
    background: #add8e6;
    
}

.aTable{
    width:85%;
    
}
    .aTable  th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #DDD;
    }
```

How the table should look like with the above style sheet:

[image: See screenshot].

The bottom table is fine, but the top table starts showing the vertical lines once I add the `aTable` stylesheet. Also, the bottom disappears. If I remove the `aTable` stylesheet, the top table looks like this with no vertical lines:

[image: See screenshot]

How can I keep the top table as it is and the bottom table with `.atable` stylesheet without affecting the tables with each other's styles? I want the bottom table to look like this:

[image: See screenshot]

Comment: Don't add styles to `.table`, that is a Bootstrap class with premade styles, unless of course you didn't load the Bootstrap stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to specify which table td you want to apply styling for.

Use
`.aTable td` instead of just using `td` as it will be applied for all td tags within your HTML

```css
.table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #FFF;
}

.table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #D8EBFB;
}

.table tr:first-child {
  background: #add8e6;
}

.aTable {
  width: 85%;
}

.aTable th,
.aTable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>




<table class="aTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake `.aTable  th, td` this line in the style will set to all `td`s.

Should be:

```
.aTable  th, .aTable td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #DDD;
    }
```